# How to activate ANOTHER object's actuator (Python)? Really!

Tags: python, game-engine

This question has already been asked, but not really answered: 
[How to activate ANOTHER object's actuator (Python)?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84769/how-to-activate-another-objects-actuator-python)

So regardless if I'm supposed to:

I've got following objects parented (simplified):

```
Cube "Hero" (invisible,actor) [always:player.py]
  > Armature "Skel"     [Walk.action, Jump.action, ...]
      > Mesh "Skin"
```

"Hero" is my player object. Here I have my Always > player.py script.

Depending on stuff I want my script to activate animations on "Skel".

Currently I'm doing this using `playAction` while using the settings taken from the Action from `Skel`.

Now I'd like to use the Action Actuator directly via `cont.activate(Walk.action)`.

The problem is I don't have a controller to activate it with.

How can I do this nevertheless? (And yes, I'm interested in alternatives, too, but I really really would like to have an direct approach first.)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from bge import logic

cont = logic.getCurrentController() #Camera
cube = logic.getCurrentScene().objects['Cube']
print(cube.controllers)
print(cube.actuators)
cube.controllers[0].activate(cube.actuators[0]) #AttributeError: 'SCA_ANDController' object has no attribute 'activate'
cont.activate(cube.actuators[0]) #ValueError: Motion not in this python controllers actuator list
```

The solution: Send a [message](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/search.html?q=send+message&check_keywords=yes&area=default) to trigguer a `message sensor` to trigger the `and controller` to trigger the `action actuator`

[image]

In your script:

```
from bge import logic

cont = logic.getCurrentController()

cont.owner.sendMessage('anySubject')
```

or just:

```
from bge import logic

logic.sendMessage('anySubject')
```

Also you can connect multiple objects logic bricks take a look at [blender-game-engine-logics-sensors-and-python-script](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91040/blender-game-engine-logics-sensors-and-python-script/91067#91067)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Above all I appreciate showing that/why using another objects controller doesn't work.